Obtener valor sin hacer el POST
tengo un formulario el cual, en uno de los campos llamado "Identificador", tengo un botón a su lado para generar un nuevo identificador de manera automática. Además, hay otro campo llamado "Tipo" de tipo select con dos opciones, según la opción de que coja en "Tipo", el botón de generar nuevo identificador me hace una cosa o otra.
El problema viene que no consigo coger el valor seleccionado en "Tipo" sin hacer el submit del formulario.
He probado con onchange dentro del html pero no me funciona. No se si tendra algo que ver con el proyecto que uso, que es un proyecto de codigo abierto llamado Kanboard y el plugin MetaMagik.

                     $html .=$this->helper->modal->medium('', t('Generar nuevo ID'), 'TaskCreationController', 'show2',array('project_id'  => $values['project_id'],
                     'column_id'   => $values['column_id'],
                     'swimlane_id' => $values['swimlane_id'],
                     'title' => $title,
                     $key => $values['metamagikkey_'.$key]
                     ));    

    public function medium($icon, $label, $controller, $action, array $params = array(), $title = '')
    {
        $ariaLabel = (empty($title) ? 'aria-hidden="true"' : 'role="img" aria-label="'.$title.'"');
        $html = '<i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' fa-fw js-modal-medium" '.$ariaLabel.'></i>'.$label;
        return $this->helper->url->link($html, $controller, $action, $params, false, 'js-modal-medium', $title);
    }


Hola Brian, por favor presioná [edit] y agrega tu código. PD: Todos los <button> por defecto son type="submit". Si queres que el <form> no se envíe, asegurate de indicar que el <button> sea type="button"

Hola Marcos, no he puesto el código porque funciona a través de render, el cual el html es mínimo por no decir que no hay. Mas bien era una duda sobre como coger datos sin hacer el post.

Entiendo que lo que quieres lograr es manipular el contenido de la vista sin recargar la página. En ese caso tendrías que utilizar javascript para comunicarte con el php. ¿tienes ese código para incluirlo en la pregunta?

sin javascript no hay paraíso
